# Semantic Url (ex. /example-in-city)

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the current system I've been developing, I need help tweaking the urls for more user friendly search results.

This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteRule "^new-jersey/(.*)" "location.php?c=$1" [NC,L]
```

Here is my location.php

```
<?
$city = $_GET['c'];

include "php_includes/db_conx.php";

$string = $city;

//This removes to .php
$city = substr($string, 0, -4);

//This is to search the db without the hyphens
$city2 = str_replace('-', ' ', $city);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city = '$city2'";
$records = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

$end = end(explode('/', $url));
echo $end;

while($cities=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){
    $city = $cities['city'];
    $county = $cities['county'];
}

$path0 = "/new-jersey/";

// Select the city from the cities table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city='$city' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($actual_page == $path0){
    header("Location: /locations");
    exit();
}

else if($numrows < 1){
    include ("404.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Here are the results

```
example.com/new-jersey/city1
example.com/new-jersey/city2
example.com/new-jersey/city3
```

I would like to convert this system to output the following

```
example.com/services-in-city1
example.com/services-in-city2
example.com/services-in-city3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what specific part do you need help with?

Comment: You have a number of undefined variables in this code

Comment: Isn't this just a much broader repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468835/how-to-create-custom-semantic-url)? And if your question is the result of not reading a single mod_rewrite tutorial, then it might even be adviseable to just leave it be. There's no point in burdening ones setup with magic black boxes.

Comment: I would like the urls to be accessed via example.com/services-in-city1 instead of example.com/new-jersey/city1

Comment: @mario I have sir, could you provide me with a direct link to a tutorial that would help me solve this code?